# Splitting a String and Parsing it into an Integer

Tags: java

I have some logic (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) error in this part of my code for some reason. I want the user to input anything and have it be split and parsed into an integer. If the user fails to do so ask them again. And if they enter something like "g5 3 76h 23" have the program accept it as 5 3. Or if i can have the program deny this until the user only enters two numbers between 0 and 9 separated by a space, that would be fine aswell. The user also has the option of enetering a "q" to quit.
However, everytime i run it, it appears as if nothing was split into a new array. and I get the error.

```
/** 
 * Prompts the user for input
 */
public void promptUser() {

// a Scanner object that uses System.in for input.

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

// a prompt for the user, asking them for input.

    System.out.print("Pick a coordinate [row col] or press [q] to quit: ");

//         Get input from the user, checking for errors. If the input is
//         correct (e.g., two numbers that in bounds and have not 
//         already been clicked), then call the click method for desired 
//         coordinates. If the user wants to quit the game then make sure 
//         to update the boolean state variable and print out a message.

    String input = scan.next();
    String del = "[\\s,;\\n\\t]+"; // these are my delimiters
    String[] token = input.split(del); // here i will save tokens

    int val0 = 11, val1 = 11;
    boolean tf = true;
    while(tf)
    {
    if(token[0] == "q")
        {
        isRunning = false;
                    System.out.println("Thank you for playing");
        }
    else
        {
        try
            {
            val0 = Integer.parseInt(token[0], 10);
            }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
            // invalid data - set to impossible
            val0 = 11;
            }
        try
            {
            val1 = Integer.parseInt(token[1], 10);
            }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
            // invalid data - set to impossible
            val1 = 11;
            }
        }
    if( !(((val0 >= 0) && (val0 < rows)) && ((val1 >= 0) && (val1 < cols))) )
        {
        System.out.println("Input Invalid, pick a coordinate [row col] or press [q] to quit: ");
        input = scan.next();
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
            token = input.split(del);
            }
                }
            else if(false) //atm
                {

                }
            else
        {
                    tf = false;


                }
    click(val0, val1);
    } //while loop
} // promptUser
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Scanner documentation:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

You could change it to:

```
scan.useDelimiter(del); // If you want to split on more than just whitespace
while(scan.hasNext()) {
    String input = scan.next();

    if("q".equals(input)) {
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing");
        return;
    }
    // etc. Put in a list or array for use later.
}
```

Remember that Strings are objects so `==` only returns true if both strings are the same object, not if they have the same value. Use `.equals` for value comparison.

Comment: This worked. Yeah, I realized the scan.next() was the method I actually needed to implement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to validate the length of your returned `token[]` array, as it is possible that no "tokens" are returned.  I.E., you shouldn't try to access `token[0]` and `token[1]` without first ensuring that they exist.

An example check:

```
if(token.length > 1)
```

Comment: I have been doing research and everywhere i look says that the .split() method returns a new array with a length of 1. I tested this out and it appears to be correct. If this is true, then i need some other way to split my array. How would I do this?

Comment: @user1655986 - In general, you should always check the bounds before accessing.  In this particular case, you' are correct - per the Javadoc: "If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string."  However, this only guarantees a `token[0]` - which means that you're most likely receiving the exception when accessing a non-existent `token[1]` (which would require a length of 2).

Comment: So i have run my debugger and it appears that the .split(del) is only returning the first instance before any of my delimiters. 
Example ( If i 
input "3 5 6 7" the result becomes 
token[0] : 3,
token[1] : doesnt exist...
)  
why?

Comment: @user1655986 - What you just mentioned works for me.  `System.out.println("3 5 6 7".split("[\\s,;\\n\\t]+").length);` shows `4`.  You may want to continue debugging.  :-)

Comment: Apparently the .split method is buggy... how do i get around this?

Comment: @Agemoz - I highly doubt that.  Please ensure that both the input and regex that you're passing-in to `split` at run-time are what you expect.